# Navbar not functioning like it's supposed to

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a Navbar which changes it's image/logo, background color & font color when i scroll down a little however nothing i have tried so far has worked

Also want the image that appears when i scroll down to have the same width and height as the previous one

[Here's my code](https://codepen.io/Senenzo/pen/oVOONX)

> **Js :**

```
$(function () { 
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) { 
            $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','https://www.luatix.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo_menu_text.png');
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1000) { 
            $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','https://www.luatix.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo_menu_text_white.png');
        }
    })
});

$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".navbar-brand");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
```

Comment: what if you are at 1000 px ;)

Comment: Your code pen does not have jQuery in seems

Comment: make sure to add jQuery, you don't have it in your codepen. If you activate it, the logo changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you are not importing jQuery in your codepen, so the code you wrote there will not work; by including it you should see the logo changing; however the `scrollTop() > 1000` is too much, maybe reduce it to like `50` and you'll see the image of the logo actually change after you scroll

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src', 'https://www.luatix.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo_menu_text.png');
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
      $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src', 'https://www.luatix.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo_menu_text_white.png');
    }
  })
});

$(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var $nav = $(".navbar-brand");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}


/* Global */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Header **/

header {
  background-color: #00695c;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight,
header .current a {
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-brand.scrolled {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<!-- Make sure to add this import -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding" class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="https://www.luatix.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo_menu_text_white.png" alt="" width="123" height="50" style="height:100%;">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="space" style="height:1400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have jquery well imported, it works in my compute.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been making some test, So I suggest your something like this:

```js
$(function() {
    var header = $(".header");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    
        if (scroll >= 200) {
            header.removeClass('header').addClass("header-alt");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("header-alt").addClass('header');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 200;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.header img {
  background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif) no-repeat;
}
.header-alt {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 200;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  color: blue;
}

.header-alt img{
  background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg) no-repeat;

}


.otherSection {  
  height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
    <img class="img" width="42" height="42">
    <h1>I'm a navigation bar<h1/>
</header>

<div class="otherSection">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import jQuery. Here is the code you need: This is their slim / min core link.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```